# How to pass context variable in a ModelField?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using Django 1.8.

I want to use a CharField with an internal context variable.

For example,

```
in models.py
...
  content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
...
```

in template:

```
...
  {{ model_instance.content }}
...
```

The output in html:

```
...
The content of a context variable is {{ request.variable }}
...
```

But I want to get:

```
...
The content of a context variable is test-test-test
...
```

How can I accomlpish it? I used `{{ model_instance.content|safe }}`, but it had no effect.

Comment: You want to treat your `content` field contents as a template and render it with some context variables, like request. Right?

Comment: Check out my answer then:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple template tag will do it:

## yourapp/templatetags/yourapp_tags.py

```
from django.template import Template

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render(context, content):
    return Template(content).render(context)
```

## yourapp/templates/template.html

```
{% load yourapp_tags %}
{% render model_instance.content %}
```

Just make sure your content fields are not writable for plain site users, as it imposes a security risk.